# Is there a way to change the read-only setting of the editor in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio

I just installed VS Code and tried to test out a basic python calculator on it which accepts raw input value, however I am unable to write any inputs in the editor as it is displays the message `Cannot edit in read-only editor`. Is there a way to change this setting or get around it and input values in a different way?

Here is the calculator:

```
degC = input("What is the temp in Celsius?")

degF = int(degC) * 9/5 + 32

print (str(degC) + " degrees Celsius = " + str(degF) + " degrees Fahrenheit")
```

I expect to be able to enter a value when prompted to do so in the editor, but am unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call your script from a terminal, like

> python yourScript.py

or

> C:\Python27\python.exe C:..\yourScript.py

Have a look here: [How to Run a Python Script via a File or the Shell](https://www.pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/)